# Resizing when using amsart

Tags: formatting, article, amsart

The following code produces margins that I like:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\paperheight=11in
\paperwidth=8.5in
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.05}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\topmargin0.0cm
\headheight0.0cm
\headsep0.0cm
\oddsidemargin0.0cm
\textheight23.0cm
\textwidth16.5cm
\footskip1.0cm

\title{Demo for Stack}
\author{Eric Auld}
\date{November 16, 2016}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section{First Section}
\lipsum[1]  \par \lipsum[2] \par \lipsum[3] \par \lipsum[4] \par \lipsum[5] \par \lipsum[6] \par \lipsum[7] \par \lipsum[8] \par \lipsum[9] \par \lipsum[10]
\end{document}
```

Now I wanted to use the `amsart` package instead. When I do so, just changing the previous code to `amsart` and keeping everything the same, I get this:

[image]

The first page is fine, but the following problems arise on the pages two and above:

- The page numbers are missing
- The text is all shifted to the right--left margin too big, and right margin too small
- The headers are bumping into the text.

Is there an easy way to get the same sizing as above in `amsart`?

Update: Using the code in egreg's answer, examine the difference in the spacing of displayed math:

Here is with my previous method:

[image]

And here is with the code egreg suggests. Notice how the displayed math has less vertical space around it?

[image]

Comment: the "geometry" of `amsart` is defined in such a way that the resulting layout is reliably positioned for automatic placement onto plates for the press.  the `geometry` package cannot accommodate this requirement.  the answer by @egreg takes this into account.  however, unless you are submitting to the ams, you are free to ignore this recommendation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the relevant parameters and issue `\calclayout`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.05}

\setlength{\textheight}{23.0cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16.5cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{0cm}% probably not wanted with amsart
\setlength{\footskip}{1.0cm}
\calclayout

\title{Demo for Stack}
\author{Eric Auld}
\date{November 16, 2016}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section{First Section}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Since `amsart` fills the headers, you probably don't really want to set the `\headsep` to zero.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. Have you noticed that in the format you gave, compared to the one I was previously using, there is less vertical space allotted for displayed math? (See the pictures which I've added to my question.) Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I see no difference: note that `amsart` does differently from `article` with respect to the spacing around displays.

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to modify this parameter, if I want all the good stuff of `amsart`, but I want the vertical spacing as it is in `article`?

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to adjust (or set) the layout of your document, use [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  paper = letterpaper,
  margin = 1in,
  includehead,
  footskip = 1cm
}

\title{Demo for TeX.SE}
\author{An Author}
\date{\today}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{First Section}\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```